# Optimization in R and Python using optim and minimize functions

Tags: python, r, optimization

I have a code in R that uses parscale inside the `optim` function from the stats package.

```
optim(par = params, fun = myFun, method = "Nelder-Mead",x,y,z,..., control = list(maxit = 10000, parscale = par.scale)
```

Here `parscale` is a vector of numbers. According to the documentation, parscale is

> a vector of scaling values for the parameters. Optimization is performed on par/parscale and these should be comparable in the sense that a unit change in any element produces about a unit change in the scaled value.

I'm trying to write the Python equivalent using the `minimize` function from `scipy.optimize`. So far, I got

```
minimize(myFun, params, arg=(x,y,z...), method = 'Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-10, options={'maxiter':10000})
```

However, I'm not sure how to add the parscale part. I've got a feeling this is important since the result from `minimize` is quite different to the `optim` result.

Any ideas how to add this? Is it really important?

To add more context to the problem:

- I want to optimize all the parameters in `param`, say `a,b,c,d`.
- `myFun` is a complex and long function, but works well in both R and Python (in the sense that when you call them, they produce the same result).
- The problem is the optimization. `optim` and `minimize` produce widely different results and that is why I think the `parscale` argument might be important.

Comment: If the problem is nonconvex, different solvers can be expected to produce different results, no matter what the scaling is.

Comment: Of course, the problem is not convex, and so the solution depends on the initial point and the solver that is being used.